# How to shorten a query in mysql/php with multiple similarly named variables

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I am saving submitted user data sent through a form into a database and I'm curious to know if there is a way to shorten/optimize my code.

I have 20 textarea fields which I'm referring to in a uniform manner (text1, text2, text3, ..., text20) since there's no need to give them more specific names in this case.

```
<form action="insert_into.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" />

    <?php  
        for ($x = 1; $x <= 21; $x++) {
          echo "<textarea name='text" . $x . "'
          placeholder='Write...'></textarea>";
        }
    ?> 

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now this means that when I go to retrieve the data to save it in the db, my code ends up looking kind of... repetitive/redundant:

```
<?php

include('db-connect.php');

$name = $_POST['name'];

$text1 = $_POST['text1'];
$text2 = $_POST['text2'];
$text3 = $_POST['text3'];
$text4 = $_POST['text4'];
$text5 = $_POST['text5'];
$text6 = $_POST['text6'];
$text7 = $_POST['text7'];
$text8 = $_POST['text8'];
$text9 = $_POST['text9'];
$text10 = $_POST['text10'];
...
...
...
$text20 = $_POST['text20'];

$insert = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, text1, text2,  
text3, text4, text5) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$text1', '$text2', '$text3',  
'$text4', '$text5', '$text6', '$text7', '$text8', '$text9', '$text10',  
'$text11', '$text12', '$text13', '$text14', '$text15', '$text16', '$text17',  
'$text18', '$text19', '$text20')");

header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

I feel like this could be optimized through a loop or an array or both but I'm not sure how to even begin. I tried to work it out with a loop

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 21; $x++) {

    $texts = '$text' . $x;
    $texts = $_POST[$texts];

}

$insert = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, text1, text2,  
text3, text4, text5) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$text1', '$text2', '$text3',  
'$text4', '$text5', '$text6', '$text7', '$text8', '$text9', '$text10',  
'$text11', '$text12', '$text13', '$text14', '$text15', '$text16', '$text17',  
'$text18', '$text19', '$text20')");
```

because I thought it'd give me an output like this

```
$text1 = $_POST['text1'];
$text2 = $_POST['text2'];
$text3 = $_POST['text3'];
...
$text20 = $_POST['text20'];
```

but the values aren't getting saved in the db this way. Not sure if this is because "$texts = $_POST[$texts];" doesn't work or because the mysql query is outside of the loop... ?

Comment: You should definitely start looking at prepared statements - the current code is widely open to SQL injection

Comment: I dont think you can do better than what you already have, since there is no way to use loops in sql queries. However you can use prepared statements to avoid sql injjection attacks in your code. Mysqli driver supports them

Comment: have you try checking your query to print, can you see the values in the query

Comment: With `$texts = $_POST[$texts];` you are only overwriting the current content of the variable $texts, this does not create a new variable with the _name_ that $texts currently contains - the correct way to achieve that, is described here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: But you should rather not use variable variables to begin with, almost always using an array is the better alternative. Name your form fields `name="text[]"`, then you will get an array of the values in `$_POST['text']`. You can also specify the index upfront `name="text[0]"`, `name="text[1]"`, etc., if you need to maintain index associations with other fields (such as f.e. checkboxes, which will only submit a value if they are checked, otherwise they are missing from the form submission data set.)

Comment: It is maybe a better idea to normalize your tables. Split them up into 2 tables. For example: _user (id, name)_ and _user_details (user_id, name, value)_. You can then loop over your post data and insert multiple rows into _user_details_ instead of inserting multiple columns.

Comment: you also might want to research what SQL injections are as your current code is vulnerable to that

Answer (score -1):

I didnt test this, but the idea seems ok.

```
$names = ['id','name'];
$values = ['NULL', $name];
foreach ($_POST as $key => $inputVal) {
  for ($i=1; $i <= 10; $i++) {  // $i<= number of similar fields
    if ($key == 'text'.$i) {
        $names[] = 'text'.$i
        $values[] = $inputVal;
    }
   }
 }

 $query = "INSERT INTO mytable (". implode(',', $names) .") 
    VALUES (". implode(',', $values) .")";
```